# Slicing a mesh of unknown dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to do a grid search over a model I've trained. So, producing a mesh, then predicting that mesh with the model to find a maximum.
I'm producing the mesh with:

```
def generate_random_grid(n_scanning_parameters,n_points_each_dimension):
  points=np.linspace(1,0,num=n_points_each_dimension,endpoint=False)
  x_points=[points for dimension in range(n_scanning_parameters)]
  mesh=np.array(np.meshgrid(*x_points))
  return mesh
```

As you can see, I don't know the dimensions in advance. So later when I want to index the mesh to predict different points, I don't know how to index.
E.g, if I have 4 dimensions and 10 points along each dimension, the mesh has the shape (4,10,10,10,10). And I need to access points like e.g. [:,0,0,0,0] or [:,1,2,3,4]. Which would give me a 1-D vector with 4 elements.
Now I can produce the 4 last indices using

`for index in np.ndindex(*mesh.shape[1:]):`

, but then indexing my mesh like `mesh[:,index]` doesn't result in a 1-D vector with 4 elements as I expect it to.

How can I index the mesh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with tuples, and numpy supports tuple indexing, let's start with that.

Effectively, you want to do your slicing like `a[:, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. But your index is a tuple, and you're attempting something like `a[:, (0,0,0,0)]` - this gives you four hyperplanes along the second dimension instead. Your indexing should be more like `a[(:,0,0,0,0)]` - but this gives a syntax error.

So the solution would be to use the `slice` built-in.

```
a[(slice(None),0,0,0,0)]
```

This would give you your one dimensional vector.

In terms of your code, you can simply add the tuples to make this work.

```
for index in np.ndindex(*mesh.shape[1:]):
    vector = mesh[(slice(None), ) + index]
```

An alternative approach would be to simply use a transposed array and reversed indices. The first dimension is at the end, removing the need for `:`.

```
for index in np.ndindex(*mesh.shape[1:]):
    vector = mesh.T[index[::-1]]
```